# How to override controllers in resources.groovy depending on environment?

Tags: grails

I have a scenario where I want to override certain controllers during functional tests, so that at runtime mock controllers are invoked. I can easily override services in resources.groovy like this: (documented [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#springdsl) and [here](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/02/08/grails-testing-mocking-3rd-party-services/).)

```
 // grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
beans = {
    switch(Environment.current) {
        case Environment.TEST:
            expensiveToUseService(MockExpensiveToUseService)

            break
    }
}
```

This approach redirects to the mock service correctly when the app is run in a test environment.

The same approach used with a controller does not work however. This is my current attempt:

```
// grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
beans = {
    switch(Environment.current) {
        case Environment.TEST:
            expensiveToUseController(MockExpensiveToUseController)

            break
    }
}
```

The mocked controller is in the same directory/package as the original, under *grails-app/controllers.*

The only obvious difference that I can see is that my services are explicitly referenced in code by the controllers that use them, e.g.

```
class ExpensiveToUseController { 
    def expensiveToUseService
...
}
```

The controllers on the other hand are only referenced by the Grails runtime.

Probably worth mentioning, I dont have the option of moving the logic out of the existing controllers into services, which would provide a workaround.

Is there something I'm missing here, or is there another way of achieving this?

**Edit: See answer below.**

For anyone else that encounters this issue, I didn't need the extra bean.scope/autowire params. This is my DSL:

```
beans = {
switch(Environment.current) {
    case Environment.TEST:
        'com.example.ExpensiveToUseController'(com.example.MockExpensiveToUseController)

        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're not intended to be autowireable, controllers are registered in the spring context under a bean name that matches their fully qualified class name, not the "property name" representation used by services.  So you'd need to register your test beans as `com.example.ExpensiveToUseController` instead of `expensiveToUseController`.

But it may be easier to put the environment check inside the "expensive" actions of the controller itself. I presume the act of *instantiating* the controller can't be too expensive seeing as controllers are prototype scope by default.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already tried this, and re-tried now but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: resources"


I'd rather not put the environment checks inside the controllers, I'd like to keep my test code entirely separate.

Comment: @eustachio you'll have to quote it in the beans DSL: `'com.example.ExpensiveToUseController'(MockExpensiveToUseController) { bean -> bean.scope = 'prototype' ; bean.autowire = 'byName' }`